# Is there a way in pyspark to extract digits /alphabets from alphanumeric column

Tags: pyspark

I want to extract the numerical digits from an alphanumeric string column into another column which will contain only digits and not alphabets using pyspark.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Agree, this is a good question, but make sure you add your data so others can help you. I know answer already added a data for example, but it always help to know what your exact issue is.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`regexp_replace`** function with `\D` to replace all non digit characters in the string.

**Example:**

```
df.withColumn("ns",regexp_replace(col("id"),"(\D)","")).show()
#+------+---+
#|    id| ns|
#+------+---+
#|a1b2c4|124|
#+------+---+
```